# Rails changing database connection inside a controller

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I created a REST API with rails 3.

I use namespace to create virtual environnement development and production, myapi.net/dev/function redirect to a controller in dev directory.

Everything works fine except that my app is now in production and I would like to use the development database when the url called contain /dev/

I know I can change the database in my model, but the model is the same in dev and prod.

Is there a way to do this ?

I know this is not really best practices when using an MVC but I need to do this before creating a real environnement.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

[establish_connection](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class) is what you're looking for.

In your controller method:

```
def function
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :development
  ...
end
```

Comment: It seems it doesnt' work :( When I try, got production datas !

Comment: hi! I'd be useful if you explained whatever you did to solve this